# Can I insert an M.2 pci-e 3.0 x4 on an M.2 slot that only supports pci-e 2.0?

Tags: ssd, pci-express, m.2

My motherboard is an Asus prime h310m-c and the ssd that I wanted to buy is xpg spectrix s40g m.2 2280 m.2 2280 .
Will this work on my pc?

Comment: PCIe is backwards compatible